# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CLIENT_ENDPOINT with amazon ses and secrets manager

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ses, aws-secrets-manager

Getting this issue while trying to use aws secrets manager and AWS SES.

I saw someone mentioning that the SES,secrets manager and ses versions has to be same.
tried matching these sdk versions but still no use.

Below is the code with all the screenshots

```
public GetSecretValueResult getSecret() {

String secretName = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:451175727313:secret:Bank-Credentials-NiVwoM";
String region = "ap-south-1";


AWSSecretsManager client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();

String secret, decodedBinarySecret;
GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName);
GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

try {
    getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
} catch (DecryptionFailureException e) {

    throw e;
}

if (getSecretValueResult.getSecretString() != null) {
    secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
} else {
    decodedBinarySecret = new String(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(getSecretValueResult.getSecretBinary()).array());
}

    return getSecretValueResult;
}
```

[image]
Below is the project structure and dependency.

Below is the full stacktrace:-> this is specific to secrets manager, i'm getting the similar issue even with aws-ses , I beleive it might be a common issue.

Please help me out here!!

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CLIENT_ENDPOINT
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.executeGetSecretValue(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:904)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.getSecretValue(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:886)
    at scraper.rubix.utils.SecretsManager.getSecret(SecretsManager.java:34)
    at scraper.rubix.web.MCAController.secretTest(MCAController.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Your code looks right, your pom.xml looks right too .. 
It looks you have a awscredentials setup issue.
I tried the same code, it worked for me.

Comment: Try adding this to your pom.xml ..

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.108</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>